# Javascript canvas collision side detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

Hey i'm trying to get the side with which the two objects in the canvas collide. Here's what i'm using for collision detection, but it only checks for a collision, without a specific side.

Where o1 and o2 are objects taht have properties:

`x` - position on the X axis
`y` - position on the Y axis
`w` - the width of the rectangle
`h` - the height of the rectangle

```
var collidesWith = function (o2) {
    var o1 = this;
    if ((o1.y + o1.h) < o2.y) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (o1.y > (o2.y + o2.h)) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ((o1.x + o1.w) < o2.x) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (o1.x > (o2.x + o2.w)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
};
```

**EDIT**: Here's the code i came up for the collision detection on the top of the element:

```
if (
    (o1.y - o1.dy >= o2.y) &&
    (o1.y - o1.dy <= o2.y + o2.h) &&
    (o1.x + o1.w >= o2.x) &&
    (o1.x <= o2.x + o2.w)
) {
    // We have collision at the top end
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need *double*-conditions like this:

```
if ((o1.y > o2.y) && (o1.y < o2.y + o2.h)) {
  return 'top'; // o1's top border collided with o2's bottom border
}
```

Similarily for other sides.

Comment: Well, i had to make a whole lot more calculations to make this work properly, but you showed me the way. Thanks :)

Comment: Would be great if you could share the calculations you had to make. Would finish this question off nicely :)