# Seeing if two rectangles have hit in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making my first game in HTML5, and I need to figure out how to tell if two rectangles hit each other. So far, I'm really not sure how. Here is the code that I've tried, but it only works when the enemy is hitting the this's draw point. Here it is so far:

```
if(this.drawX >= enemies[i].drawX && this.drawX <= enemies[i].drawX + enemies[i].width && this.drawY >= enemies[i].drawY && this.drawY <= enemies[i].drawY + enemies[i].height) {
```

I'm confused on how to do this right. Could anyone help me?

Edit: I tried this code:

```
if (!(this.drawX + this.width < enemies[i].drawX ||
        enemies[i].drawX + enemies[i].width < this.drawX ||
        this.drawY + this.height < enemies[i].drawY ||
        enemies[i].drawY + enemies[i].height < this.drawY)) {
                   gameOver();
           }
```

The code seems to make that the game end almost randomly. How can I fix it, also, sorry for waiting so long.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098002/javascript-canvas-collision-side-detection

Answer (score 0):

If the rectangles intersect, then the corner of one rectangle must be inside the other rectangle (assuming they are not rotated).  Write a function that takes a rectangle and a point and returns true if the point is inside the rectangle.  Then call that function 8 times (once for each corner) and combine the results with `||`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function like this

```
function (rectA, rectB) {
  return !(rectA.x + rectA.width < rectB.x ||
           rectB.x + rectB.width < rectA.x ||
           rectA.y + rectA.height < rectB.y ||
           rectB.y + rectB.height < rectA.y);
};
```

Comment: yes, this should work. It basically checks all the possibilities of the rectangles NOT intersecting. and if all the non-intersecting properties are false, function returns true. Use it and see what it does. You may also want to draw a diagram on a paper and test these conditions manually

Comment: must be some bug in the way you are using 'this'. Cant say anything without seeing the full function

Comment: So are you saying that function should work if I call the right variables?